# Binomial Distribution Intuition

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, intuition

For the Binomial Distribution

${\displaystyle{n \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}}$

I'm trying to understand the intuition of the factors.  I understand that the probability of $k$ successes is $p^k$, and the probability of the remaining $(n-k)$ being non-successes is $(1-p)^{n-k}.$  I also understand that ${n \choose k}$ is the number of ways $k$ successes can appear across $n$ samples.

The thing I am having trouble with, however, is that the last two factors are probabilities, and the first factor is a number of combinations, but yet the result of multiplying them all together is a probability.  How does a number of combinations * a probability * a probability = a probability?  Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: You said it yourself, *"the probability of k successes is $p^k$"*, what's different now? $p^k$ is a multiplication of probabilities and result in a probability too.

Comment: @Firebug I understand that.  I think I was not clear with my question.  How does a number of samples * a probability = another probability.  Shouldn't it equal a number of samples?  The probability is being applied to a real number of samples, so the result should be a smaller number of samples, not another probability.

Comment: Read the first part of [this answer of mine](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/249511/6633) to a recent question.

Comment: @DilipSarwate aha!  It's clear now!  The binomial coefficient is just the shortened expansion of the sums of probabilities.

Comment: The multiplication is just a summing of mutually exclusive outcomes where you have k successes in n trials. Each has the probaibility p^k (1-p)^(n-k) .

Comment: You could have got it from my comment above but I guess the light bulb went off when you saw it explicitly in Dilip Sarwate's answer to the earlier question.

Comment: Yes, thank you @MichaelChernick, that solidified it for me.